# Numbering and text alignment with enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate

There are a multitude of options to specify the alignment and spacing with the enumerate package however I am unable to find the combination which yields the formatting I want.

The \lipsum package is used to illustrate the formatting.

---

Using the options below, each item in enumerate (1st and 2nd levels) has the same indentation (left margin) for every line in each 1st level of enumerate. This is what I want. However I would also like the section and 1st level enumerate numbers to be left aligned.

I have included the 2nd level of enumerate which is appearing as desired with the (a) at the same alignment as the text in the 1st level.

```
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelwidth=1.5cm,labelindent=10pt,leftmargin=1.2cm}
```

[image]

---

In order to make the section numbering and first level enumerate numbering aligned on the left, I changed to using the following options;

```
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelsep*=12pt, align=left, leftmargin=*}
```

[image]

However now the indentation of the paragraph is not constant.

---

Below I have taken a screen shot and moved text around in paint to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. I am less/not particularly concerned about the section heading text and paragraph text having the same alignment as each other.

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

---

Here is  MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Section numbers and enumerate numbers are not left aligned, however the indentation of text is constant (how I want it)
% \setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelwidth=1.5cm,labelindent=10pt,leftmargin=1.2cm}

% Section numbers and enumerate numbers are left aligned, however the indentation of the text is not constant
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelsep*=12pt, align=left, leftmargin=*}

\setenumerate[2]{label=(\alph*), ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*), align=left}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{section}{22}
\section{Double digits}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \setcounter{enumi}{21}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2] % The (a) should be aligned with the text in the item above
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `widest`key for that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Section numbers and enumerate numbers are not left aligned, however the indentation of text is constant (how I want it)
% \setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelwidth=1.5cm,labelindent=10pt,leftmargin=1.2cm}

% Section numbers and enumerate numbers are left aligned, however the indentation of the text is not constant
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,labelsep*=12pt, widest=00.00, align=left, leftmargin=*}

\setenumerate[2]{label=(\alph*), ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*), align=left}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{section}{22}
\section{Double digits}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \setcounter{enumi}{21}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2] % The (a) should be aligned with the text in the item above
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]